# $\sum_{n=1}^m |a_n-a_{n+1}|=2009$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

You define the sequence of complex numbers $ \{a_n \} _ {n \geq 1} $ by $ a_n = (1 + i) \cdot \left (1+ \frac {i} {\sqrt {2}} \right) \cdot .... \cdot \left (1+ \frac {i} {\sqrt {n}} \right) $. There is a natural number $ m $ such that$$\sum_{n=1}^m |a_n-a_{n+1}|=2009$$?

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Compare https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h447057p2515949 on AoPS.

Comment: Have you actually tried evaluating $\sum_1^m|a_n-a_{n+1}|$ for $m=1,2,3$? Surely if you do the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$a_{n=}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$

then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left|a_{n}-a_{n-1}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}\right)-\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\left(\frac{i}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right|$$

can you continue?